# windows batch: how to check if network has been disconnected any time?

Tags: windows, batch-file, networking

I want to know if it is possible (and how) to detect if the network connection has been crashed down any time. I've created a little script with checks it but it is checking the network through a ping every few seconds and it is not working fine. I've been told that the microcuts are not detected.

This is the source:

```
@echo off

:: Interval of time the network is checked: 30 seconds
set delay_time=30
:: Delay between the kill and the start of the process
set delay_time_kill_start=5
:: Example process to kill and start
set process_to_kill=calc.exe
set process_to_start=calc.exe
:: local network to ping to check the connection
set ping_url=10.51.111.223 -n 1 -w 1000

:test-connection
Ping %ping_url%
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo No hay conexión
    :is-connected
    Ping %ping_url%
    if errorlevel 1 (
        @echo on
        echo trying to connect
        @echo off

        timeout 10
        goto :is-connected
    ) else (
        @echo on
        echo kill the process
        @echo off

        taskkill /IM %process_to_kill% /f
        timeout %delay_time_kill_start%

        @echo on
        echo start the process
        @echo off

        %process_to_start%
        goto test-connection
    )
) else (
    timeout %delay_time%
    goto test-connection
)

pause
```

Basically what I want is to kill a process and start it again when the network connection has been lost at any time, because that process freezes when the connection crashes.

So I would like to check, for instance, every 30 minutes if the network connection was lost at any time in the past half hour and, if yes, then kill and start the process.

Is it possible without doing the ping strategy every few seconds?

Comment: You can't put a label in an if statement.

Comment: Afaik, those "microcuts" are handled on hardware (or driver?) level (I think up to a few seconds). They are not even communicated to windows, so your chances of detecting them are ... very near to zero.

Comment: So there is no way to restart a process which freezes? I asked for checking the network because that's when it is happening, but if there was another way to detect if a process is freezed in order to restart it, it would be great.